# C++ Qt - How to capture keyboard and mouse events at the same time

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, mouse

I'm building a simple level editor for my game using Qt. To navigate the 3d scene i need to use the keyboard and the mouse at the same time.

This is what i have so far and it works but when i move using WASD i cant look around. How to capture and respond to keyboard and mouse events at the same time ?

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton && actionCamera)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->trackMouse = true;
    }
}

void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    ui->renderWindow->trackMouse = false;
}

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_W)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->moveForward = true;
    }

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_S)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->moveBackwards = true;
    }

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_A)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->moveLeft = true;
    }

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_D)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->moveRight = true;
    }
}

void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_W)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->moveForward = false;
    }

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_S)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->moveBackwards = false;
    }

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_A)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->moveLeft = false;
    }

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_D)
    {
        ui->renderWindow->moveRight = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: QMouseEvent and QKeyEvent  can't trigger simultaneously, just think all event delivered in event queue. But it is reasonable that these two event occur in short time is  occurring  at the same time.  So keep track these two events and timing should be OK.